# Spring boot + rxjava Completable. How to execute it without blocking?

Tags: spring-boot, rx-java

I am struggling to make this work.
I have a **Spring boot** application and one of the libraries I am using uses **rxjava**.

All I have to work with is **rx.Completable**.
I need to make it run async/non blocking but I don't know how.

I tried:

```
completable.subscribe();
completable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

How can I execute the completable without blocking the execution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what I needed to do:

completable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())**.subscribe()**;

That's it.